# Building User Interface in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to android development using kotlin, I have no problem implementing functions, but i dont know how to go about the UI, does kotlin has a framework for that like flutter or i am to build my UI using XML

Answer (score 0):

`Jetpack Compose` launched recently which has a declarative approach for building the `UI` just like `flutter`. It works with `Kotlin`.

Check more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose?gclid=Cj0KCQjw0emHBhC1ARIsAL1QGNdBd-TuUQ-0gbxPZ3FIEOuFieMkaon6EyrW0kTxar1Z6abjgn1PK8AaAslLEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) :) ( you don't need to use `XML` if you are using `Jetpack Compose` in your project )

Comment: please accept it as answer to your question so that others can know this question no longer needs help :)